# Getting Rolled Up Data into Tidy Format

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidy

I have rolled up data that I am trying to get in a "tidy" format. Here is a sample of the data. Level 1 = the sum of all Level 2 or 3 items within the same Group.

Lights (2) are a subcomponent of Electrical (1). Wiring (3) and Bulbs (3) are subcomponents of Lights (2), and so forth.

200 Electrical = 82 Lights + 118 Vent

Or it can be broken down to:

200 Electrical = 60 Wiring + 22 Bulbs + 60 Detector + 20 Cable + 25 Plastic + 13 Brackets

```
Level   Group    Name     Price
1        01    Electrical  200
2        01    Lights      82
3        01    Wiring      60
3        01    Bulbs       22
2        01    Vent        118
3        01    Detector    60
3        01    Cable       20
3        01    Plastic     25
3        01    Brackets    13

1        02    Interior    500
2        02    Doors       300
3        02    Knobs       40
2        02    Trim        200
3        02    Shelves     150
4        02    Brackets    50
```

That process then repeats for Group 02 (Interior). I am trying to get this data in a tidy/more workable format so I can do some analysis without double or triple counting the price of each item. The sum of Electrical (200) and Interior (500) should be 700. But when I total my Price column we get 1840 because of items getting counted more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Not tidyverse but the data could be converted into data.tree and igraph formats which have functionality for dealing with trees and graphs and can also be used for conversion into other formats, e.g. as.list(nn) where nn is the data.tree Node object defined below is a nested list representation. See the Note at the end for the input data in reproducible form.

```
library(data.tree)
library(sqldf)
library(yaml)

# compute parents
DF2 <- sqldf("select a.*, max(b.rowid) parent
  from DF a
  left join DF b on b.Level = a.Level - 1 and b.rowid < a.rowid
  group by a.rowid")
# leaves are those rows that are not a parent
leaves <- setdiff(1:nrow(DF2), DF2$parent)

# format as a yaml string and then read the yaml into a data tree node structure
s <- sapply(1:nrow(DF2), function(i) with(DF2[i, ], paste(
       if (Level == 1) paste0("Group-", Group, ":\n"), 
       strrep(" ", Level), 
       paste0(i, Name),
       ":", 
       if (i %in% leaves) paste("\n", strrep(" ", Level), "  Price:", Price)
     )))
y <- yaml.load(unlist(strsplit(s, "\n")))
nn <- as.Node(y)
print(nn, "Price")
```

giving (continued after output)

```
                        levelName Price
1  Root                              NA
2   ¦--Group-1                       NA
3   ¦   °--1Electrical               NA
4   ¦       ¦--2Lights               NA
5   ¦       ¦   ¦--3Wiring           60
6   ¦       ¦   °--4Bulbs            22
7   ¦       °--5Vent                 NA
8   ¦           ¦--6Detector         60
9   ¦           ¦--7Cable            20
10  ¦           ¦--8Plastic          25
11  ¦           °--9Brackets         13
12  °--Group-2                       NA
13      °--10Interior                NA
14          ¦--11Doors               NA
15          ¦   °--12Knobs           40
16          °--13Trim                NA
17              °--14Shelves         NA
18                  °--15Brackets    50
```

We can also convert to an igraph object .

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)

g <- as.igraph(nn)
plot(g, vertex.shape = "none", vertex.label.cex = 0.7)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "Level   Group    Name     Price
1        01    Electrical  200
2        01    Lights      82
3        01    Wiring      60
3        01    Bulbs       22
2        01    Vent        118
3        01    Detector    60
3        01    Cable       20
3        01    Plastic     25
3        01    Brackets    13
1        02    Interior    500
2        02    Doors       300
3        02    Knobs       40
2        02    Trim        200
3        02    Shelves     150
4        02    Brackets    50"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: "Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 129, column 6 did not find expected key at line 131, column 8." I know I do not have my full dataset here, but would could be causing that error when running yaml.load?

Comment: There is something in your data that does not conform to yaml.  You will either have to diagnose it or else use one of the other methods of converting data to a Node object.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by removing any of the summary level rows but first figuring out which level 1 and 2 they belong to. See example below which relies on your data being ordered hierarchically as it comes in. You could now sum either Level1 or Level2, for example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_dups <- tribble(
   ~Level,   ~Group,    ~Name,     ~Price,
   1,       01,    'Electrical',  200,
   2,       01,    'Lights'    ,  82,
   3,       01,    'Wiring'    ,  60,
   3,       01,    'Bulbs'     ,  22,
   2,       01,    'Vent'      ,  118,
   3,       01,    'Detector'  ,  60,
   3,       01,    'Cable'     ,  20,
   3,       01,    'Plastic'   ,  25,
   3,       01,    'Brackets'  ,  13,
   1,       02,    'Interior'  ,  500,
   2,       02,    'Doors'     ,  300,
   3,       02,    'Knobs'     ,  40,
   2,       02,    'Trim'      ,  200,
   3,       02,    'Shelves'   ,  150,
   4,       02,    'Brackets'  ,  50 
)

df_unique <- df_dups %>%
   mutate(
      NameLevel1=case_when(
         Level==1~Name,
         TRUE~NA_character_
      ),
      NameLevel2=case_when(
         Level==2~Name,
         TRUE~NA_character_
      ),
      NameLevel3=case_when(
         Level==3~Name,
         TRUE~NA_character_
      )
   ) %>%
   fill(NameLevel1, .direction="down") %>%
   fill(NameLevel2, .direction="down") %>%
   filter(Level==3) %>%
   select(Group, Name, Price, Level1=NameLevel1, Level2=NameLevel2)

df_unique
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   Group Name     Price Level1     Level2
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr> 
#> 1     1 Wiring      60 Electrical Lights
#> 2     1 Bulbs       22 Electrical Lights
#> 3     1 Detector    60 Electrical Vent  
#> 4     1 Cable       20 Electrical Vent  
#> 5     1 Plastic     25 Electrical Vent  
#> 6     1 Brackets    13 Electrical Vent  
#> 7     2 Knobs       40 Interior   Doors 
#> 8     2 Shelves    150 Interior   Trim

df_unique %>%
   group_by(Level1) %>%
   summarise(
      TotPrice=sum(Price),
      .groups="drop"
   )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Level1     TotPrice
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Electrical      200
#> 2 Interior        190

df_unique %>%
   group_by(Level1, Level2) %>%
   summarise(
      TotPrice=sum(Price),
      .groups="drop"
   )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Level1     Level2 TotPrice
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 Electrical Lights       82
#> 2 Electrical Vent        118
#> 3 Interior   Doors        40
#> 4 Interior   Trim        150
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` aproach

Something like `split` shou;ld get you started.

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Level   Group    Name     Price
1        01    Electrical  200
2        01    Lights      82
3        01    Wiring      60
3        01    Bulbs       22
2        01    Vent        118
3        01    Detector    60
3        01    Cable       20
3        01    Plastic     25
3        01    Brackets    13
1        02    Interior    500
2        02    Doors       300
3        02    Knobs       40
2        02    Trim        200
3        02    Shelves     150
4        02    Brackets    50 ")
```

**code**

```
split(DT, by = c("Group", "Level"))
```

**output (list)**

```
$`1.1`
   Level Group       Name Price
1:     1     1 Electrical   200

$`1.2`
   Level Group   Name Price
1:     2     1 Lights    82
2:     2     1   Vent   118

$`1.3`
   Level Group     Name Price
1:     3     1   Wiring    60
2:     3     1    Bulbs    22
3:     3     1 Detector    60
4:     3     1    Cable    20
5:     3     1  Plastic    25
6:     3     1 Brackets    13

$`2.1`
   Level Group     Name Price
1:     1     2 Interior   500

$`2.2`
   Level Group  Name Price
1:     2     2 Doors   300
2:     2     2  Trim   200

$`2.3`
   Level Group    Name Price
1:     3     2   Knobs    40
2:     3     2 Shelves   150

$`2.4`
   Level Group     Name Price
1:     4     2 Brackets    50
```